# How do you remove Microsoft Git Provider?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I'm having an issue with VS2013 which I had connected to my visual studio online account, and was using TFS source control just fine up until I installed Git.  Now it seems that "Microsoft Git Provider" keeps overriding my settings for source control even after I manually change it back to TFS, or none then TFS.  So now I just want to remove it all together.  I tried uninstalling everything Git related, but it still remains.  I even uninstalled VS2013 completely, then reinstalled, and it's still there.

Comment: @Shahbaz. In this case it will not. The Git provider is installed along with Visual Studio. A repave will do nothing.

Comment: Hmm!  Did you `git init` some directory in your TFS working folder mapping?  Can you do a `dir .git /s` in your TFS working folders, and does it return something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update 2:**

Here's an extension that disables MS Git provider on opening a git solution:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/146b404a-3c91-46ff-932a-fb0f8b826f94

The solution doesn't seem to work anymore (as also mentioned in the blog post):

For the ones running into this article and wanting to disable the provider for other reasons (performance or files being read-only for refactoring by Resharper), I did run into this registry hack to permanently remove the MS GIT source control provider:

https://blog.rendle.io/disable-the-git-source-control-add-in-in-vs2013-permanently/

tl;dr:

- **close VS2013** then delete this whole key (or the one with a GitSCCProvider value under it):
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\SourceControlProviders\{11b8e6d7-c08b-4385-b321-321078cdd1f8}`
- Search the registry for the same GUID `11b8e6d7-c08b-4385-b321-321078cdd1f8` and remove those values or entries
  too.

**Edit:**

if you need to use a TFS GIT repository and related information from Team Explorer (like builds, etc), don't delete the GIT SCC provider because that will break too.

Comment: I deleted the registry node, searched the guid and deleted them, it works for about a day, then the next day, starting a new vs2013 (or even the existing running instance of vs2013) revived its git provider again. I'll delete it another time to see if it works longer. So far, this doesn't look like a permanent solution to me. By the way, must I close vs2013 before the deletion?

Comment: @liang always close visual studio when making registry changes. VS has a tendency to overwrite all settings on close.

Comment: The link you provided in the blog post no longer works. Here's the current link to the same blog post: https://blog.rendle.io/disable-the-git-source-control-add-in-in-vs2013-permanently/

Comment: Can be found here in VS2015: Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\SourceControlProviders

Answer (score 17):

I used procmon to see that this dll was being accessed by visual studio when switching to the Microsoft Git Provider.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider.dll"

I edited the permissions for the dll so that the user "Everyone" had no permissions for it, and VisualStudio stopped switching back To "Microsoft Git Provider" every time at startup.
Doing this means even if you try to select "Microsoft Git Provider" for the current source control plugin it does nothing and instead just shows your previous selection.

Comment: That's the only option, that worked for me with VS 2015.

Comment: This seemed to work at first but today I received an error when opening a `.cs` file: `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.CompositionFailedException: Expected 1 export(s) with contract name &quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeSense.Git.Providers.Collaboration.SccTracking.IRepositoryEvents`

Comment: The error that I mentioned above is also persistent and to get rid of it, you have to run cmd as administrator, navigate to `Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE` and execute `devenv /updateconfiguration` and then `devenv /clearcache` as noted [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4238#issuecomment-129226422)

Comment: I've painfully opened an admin cmd prompt, `cd \c:\Program Files (x86)` and then executed `del *TeamFoundation.Git.*.dll  /S /F /Q`. I get a whole screed of errors about missing extensions when VS opens, but I am able to use TFS in VS and git on the command-line for the same project. I've also [complained to MS](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/visual-studio-2019-its-impossible-to-turn-off-the/586075#T-N1389479). This is inane. YMMV and, as always, use at your own risk.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @Ade-Miller, that's actually what I needed to hear.

Turns out my issue was that one of the parent level folders of the project I was working in was set as a repo in Git: C:\users[me].  Not sure how that happened.  But apparently VS doesn't like trying to figure out what the hell you've got going on in that sort of scenario, even though the project itself was set to use TFS.  Deleting the ".git" folder from the top level folder made everything start to behave better.

Comment: As it says above don't delete the GIT SCC if you want to use TFS GIT.  However, this answer here cleared up all sorts of weird bugs that would not let the GIT provider to start up properly.  Remove hidden .git folder and everything is peachy!

Answer (score 1):

Following did the trick for me (source: http://researchaholic.com/2015/02/02/remove-the-microsoft-gitprovider-from-visual-studio-2013/)

Note two extra steps I added:
1. I did make a backup of all registry keys by exporting them before deleting.
2. I also deleted all instances of {11b8e6d7-c08b-4385-b321-321078cdd1f8}

- Make sure Visual Studio is closed
- Open regedit
- Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\SourceControlProviders
- Delete 11b8e6d7-c08b-4385-b321-321078cdd1f8
- In the details pane it should say GitProvider
- Open Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

Just run the installer again...

In my case, the installer was `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider.msi` and choose the `remove` option.