# Visual Studio 2013/2015 Idle CPU usage

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I'm currently evaluating Visual Studio 2015 RC. I've noticed when running the IDE, The Visual Studio 2015 process is constantly at around 25% CPU usage. Even without a project loaded and without the welcome page it is gobbling up 25% CPU usage at a constant rate. No other applications running other than background services. All other running processes use around an additional 2 to 4 percent CPU overall.

This behavior has also been noticed in Visual Studio 2013.

Is anyone else seeing this behavior? Is this normal? Any suggestions?

Comment: I see this to and would really like a fix. Because it makes my fan go crazy.

Comment: I have resharper and see that when I open my solution (DNN) it takes around 40%. I often open 2 or 3 solutions (in vs 2013) now it's not possible and often are on 100% processors ... (I have a i5)

Comment: same problem here DNN solution, reshaper 9.1.3

Comment: A little late, but I am having a similar problem. Are you running in Administrator mode ? [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797768/visual-studio-2015-running-as-administrator-uses-a-lot-of-cpu) seems to point out that running VS in Administrator mode could cause some performance issues

Comment: I've seen this same problem in VS2013 (through multiple updates) despite disabling Git integration etc. as various discussions have suggested. Kind of a bummer on a laptop.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1929175/visual-studio-uses-a-lot-cpu

Comment: Microsoft tooling has just gotten worse and worse. My 4th-gen Quad-Core i7 is using 80-100% CPU when in debug mode with VS2015 on a single WebApi project. Unacceptable.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2036016/after-close-process-is-still-running-with-hight-cpu-use

Comment: I pulled my hair out over this for a few weeks.  I turned the Browser Link off.  I disabled or uninstalled all of my extensions.  I turned off source control.  Eventually the solution I settled on was uninstalling VS 2015 and reverting to VS 2013... :/

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Had this same problem. Processor constantly at 45-50% even when the IDE is completely idle.

Turns out the problem is the Microsoft Git Source Code provider.

I turned that off and processor dropped to 0 and the IDE became much more usable.

Comment: Turning it off helped me (tiny solution located in a complex Git repo). I don't have a better solution than turning it off either.

Comment: And how *did* you turn it off? Where do you find it?

Comment: Turn off here: Tools > Options > Source Control

Comment: Turning it off helped for me. I liked the Git integration, but constant 60% CPU load is no good. It even continued running after closing down VS2015.

Comment: Git sometimes turns itself on again. Have a look a look here for a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33627964/1127498

Comment: Does this impact performance even if your project isn't using Git? My source control plug-in is set to TFS, but I still get this problem.

Comment: using ankh. no git. same problem

Comment: This worked for me. Opened solution, did nothing, watched while CPU usage climbed to 15%. Turned off Git in Tools > Options > Source Control and it immediately dropped to 0%.

Comment: I noticed high CPU with a new git repo, and it was because it tracks changes to disk and (I think) calculates hashes for newly created files. In my case I'd forgotten to add a .gitignore, therefore every rebuild caused it to calc hashes for several megabytes of build output.

Comment: Thanks! That helped me a lot!

Comment: Changing Tools>Options>Source Control from Visual Studio Team Foundation Server to None dropped my idle CPU usage to 0%. Good call.

Comment: This was the problem for me also in Visual Studio 2013. HOWEVER, just changing Tools>Options>Source Control from Visual Studio Team Foundation Server to None did not solve the problem, because the setting kept reverting to Visual Studio Team Foundation Server. Following this answer helped me disable Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider.dll to stop it from being able to be used at all: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29613596/384670 (In my case instead of changing the file permissions I just changed the name to Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider.dllx.)

Comment: My solution had several thousand files. Turning it off resolved it.

Answer (score 9):

In my case disabling Telerik ASP.NET MVC Extension solved high CPU issue.

High CPU load started on solution load and didn't drop (40% with one, 80% with two solutions) until VS was closed or even sometimes after (had to kill the process).

Tools->Extensions and Updates->Installed, find the extension and click 'Disable'.

Comment: How to disable Telerik ASP.NET MVC Extension from Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Thanks buddy this was a real help to my productivity. Had been haunting me for months

Comment: @MayurPatel sorry for not answering, didn't notice your comment. Maybe it will help someone else. Tools->extensions and updates->installed->disable

Comment: Thanks, @Michael Brennt for the response. BTW I have fixed it some how. I think you should update answer showing steps to disable Telerik ASP.NET MVC Extension from Visual Studio 2015 that would be better rathe than comment.

Answer (score 3):

In my case all reference counts tried to update every time when I edit code.
[image]

I have just turned them off. You can do it [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17848184/1277458).

Answer (score 2):

It’s not to be expected that Visual Studio should chew up continuous CPU time.

I am running Visual Studio 2015 Community RTM right now with a medium sized project open, and am not seeing any ongoing CPU usage (according to Process Hacker 2, which shows usage as small as 0.01 percent). It’s just blank, which means not even 0.01% CPU usage is registering.

Keep in mind that IntelliSense scans your project files in the background to build the database for popping up its suggestions, etc.

Choosing **Project** > **Rescan Solution** from the menus will result in that process being done over, which will cause the CPU to be used for a time. But it should ultimately go quiet.

Seemingly forever, there have been times when deleting the Intellisense Database files and doing a full rescan solves “odd behavior” type problems.  I don’t know if it’s the “prescribed” method, but if I suspect an IntelliSense problem I just delete the .sdf file in the project folder if I want to make sure Visual Studio starts with a clean slate.  This isn’t necessary very often.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem, constant 20-40% CPU when idling (Visual Studio 2015 update 1). I noticed that other local repositories of the same code did not have this problem.

I deleted the problematic local repository and took a new checkout, this solved the issue for me. Why this worked, I unfortunately cannot explain...

Answer (score 2):

I run resharper, turned that off and turned off the Microsoft Git provider and still had high CPU issues, devenv.exe would also run after close... until recently.

It appears VS 2015 Update 2 has resolved these issues!

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In my case; "Visual Studio 2015 Update 1" gone crazy editing JS files regarless of the length of the source. It used high CPU and the editor is even freezed. I fixed the issue by disabling the 3rd party add-ons by one-by-to detect the buggy one causing VS 2015 malfunctioning.

Hope it works.

Comment: I had similar issue when I saved any JS file.  CPU would spike.  I found that the Telerik ASP.NET VSExtensions were causing my issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the culprit was [Node.js tools for Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/node-js-vs.aspx). I had v1.1.2 installed and the cpu was constantly around 25-40%.

A switch to Node.js Tools v1.2 RC resolved the problem completely after an initial high load that went away in a couple of minutes.

Comment: Upgrading to the latest version (1.2) solved it for me too

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was either the Roaming Extention Manager or most probably the azure worker role project in my solution. If you have one of these try unloading it and restart visual studio. I can reproduce it but I don't know why it happens.

Comment: should be a comment imho

Comment: That's true, but as you mentioned, I don't have sufficient reputation to comment.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed also that when running and stopping a debug episode on the local server, if the page is still open in the browser, VS will continue to run at high CPU. Closing the browser page stops this.

Comment: This is probably due to Browser Link being enabled in the debug menu. Untick Enable Browser Link and the problem will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my experience, 
In my case I had to diable all extensions and updates and code analysis c#.

1-For extensions and updates :

Tools => Extensions and updates

2-For the code analysis

Solution explorer => right click on the project => Properties =>Click on the tab "Code analysis" => click on the "Open" bouton => Uncheck the checkbox "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" => save and exit.

Cpu usage descended to 1 %.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, The .suo file in Visual Studio was the culprit. Deleting it fixed my issue.

Refer below link for more details.

https://shemeerns.com/2014/04/04/the-solution-user-options-suo-file-in-visual-studio/

Comment: That only means you had some setting causing this behavior that happened to be reverted by deleting the .suo file. This doesn't give any useful information as to which setting was involved.