# Visual studio 2015 high cpu consumption when idle

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have visual studio 2015 enterprise edition, update 1. 
When idle, the visual studio process is using around 10-15% cpu constantly.
I tried the solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30670566/visual-studio-2015-idle-cpu-usage) with no success.
The solution includes 11 c# projects.
The issue seems to appear only after the first compilation after the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of attempts and tests to fix this issue, I finally discovered the source of it.
I had a Code Map dgml file in the solution.
Removing the file fixed the issue, and now the devenv process cpu consumption returned to normal.

**UPDATE:**
After some time working, it seems that just removing the Code Map dgml didn't entirely solve the problem. The solution at last was to remove the reference to the "Modeling Project" containing it(along with other documents such as Sequence Diagrams...).

Comment: I have the same problem but cannot find what you are talking about. could you please elaborate on how to do this and where to find it? thanks

Answer (score 2):

In my case a few *.mdb files had been added to the solution which triggered a constant cpu usage of 30-35%.

So generally the content of a solution triggers background tasks which can lead to high cpu usage. If that usage occurs suddenly, it's worth to get maybe an older source version to check, if the problem is related to added files.

In my scenario the visual studio process remained active using cpu even after closing visual studio. Using process explorer I identified two threads using the cpu indicating following start addresses:

- clr.dll!CreateApplicationContext
- devenv.exe!IsAssertEtwEnabled