# Why does VS open an unrelated repository?

Tags: visual-studio, unreal-engine4

I see text "Opening repository: D:\Georgy2\UnrealEngine." each time I start my solution "SimpleConsoleApplication" in VS2013.
I reckon it slows down my Visual Studio for a ten minutes.
But this solution is totally unrelated to that repository.
How can I get rid of this loading?

Comment: I also has "fatal error LNK1201: error writing to program database 'project.pdb'" right after changing the webcam I am using. It may be connected.

Comment: In my experience, VS tries to open the last repository that was opened. Can you try to open some dummy repository before shutting VS down. A smaller repository may reduce load times considerably.

Comment: Yes, that pretty answers my bad-formulated question. Thanks.

Comment: Can one switch this behavior off? I do not want VS to load any repository on startup! Couldn't find the according setting yet, though...

Answer (score 0):

Described in detail here: [How can you disable Git integration in Visual Studio 2013 permanently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150060/how-can-you-disable-git-integration-in-visual-studio-2013-permanently)

Bottom line is, you can go to Tools->Options->Source Control. Then if you pick "None" in "Current source control plug-in" drop-down menu, you won't be bothered by Git related messages any longer.

But I assume that means that you simply need to use a stand-alone Git software/GUI to handle version control, as opposed to having it integrated with Visual Studio.