# How to uninstall git from Visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Please suggest the option of Uninstalling the GIT Source Control Provider. I've never used it and have used TFVC for many years. I have no intention of ever using GIT but today when I added a project to source control it went to GIT instead of TFVC even though my default provider was and always has been Visual Studio Team Foundation Server

Comment: Could you please explain what you have done already to solve your problem, so that no further work is wasted on what was fruitless?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, Below tasks are done to solve my problem 1. check the source control plug-in from VS-Tools-options-Source Contol it should be TFS. 2. Download NoGit to uninstall git. still my project is redirect to git repository only

Answer (score -4):

> I've never used it and have used TFS for many years. I have no intention of ever using GIT

Don't presuppose of the future!

There is a big switch movement for a reason (even Microsoft switched to it internally). Perhaps you should have a careful look at it because it brings a lot more flexibility and other things that could improve your development workflow.

Also FYI, the right term is `TFVC`, not `TFS` (which is the whole ALM solution and that could host `TFVC` or `git` repositories) .

Anyway...

You must not uninstall git tool but uninstall git plugin of visual studio. There are some solutions proposed (remove some registry keys or rename extension file) here:

[How can you disable Git integration in Visual Studio 2013 permanently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150060/how-can-you-disable-git-integration-in-visual-studio-2013-permanently)