# Visual Studio 2017 constantly starts a new git.exe instance

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio

I am trying to figure out why this is happening. Every time I run visual studio 2017 it continuously restarts git.exe which takes up 20% of cpu and 100 mb or ram. I am wondering if anyone could help to figure out why this is happening. Image below:

[image: Processes screenshot]

Comment: It runs numerous copies of `git` to get the status of your repository.  The question isn’t why it starts a new copy of `git`- it’s why it takes up so much resources.  How big is your repository?

Comment: For some reason Visual Studio was using the entire contents of C:/Users/me as a repository folder.. I just went ahead and disabled it. From Here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150060/how-can-you-disable-git-integration-in-visual-studio-2013-permanently

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer): that will show you the *command line* associated with those `git.exe` process, as well as their parent process.

From the command-line, you can determine what is going on.
A similar thread (for a previous version of Visual Studio) suggested also to check the [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).