# How to turn off Git in Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am getting quite annoyed with git in Microsoft Visual Studio. I see that is chewing up my CPU and my laptop is loud as hell when I turn the IDE on. Anyone got any suggestions?

I was trying https://gist.github.com/hmemcpy/5bc6b5cc11050b502ca3 but couldn't create the file in the directory even though I am an admin.

Or perhaps give a suggestion on how to use it with git but without it chewing up memory.

Comment: Then how did you draw the conclusion that turning off Git will help?

Comment: i see it in my task manager under visual studio

Comment: I figured it out. I had a repo created by accident close to the root directory. Just had to delete it, so Git won't try to process all the files in it.

Answer (score 1):

Making sure your files (currently part of your opened Visual Studio project) are not within a Git repository is one way.

The other is to try [one of the method listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55872517/6309), like:

```
Tools-->Options-->Source Control-->[Current Source Control Plug-in]
```

And select "None".

Comment: Thank you! I figured out why git was slowing down my visual studio, but I'll keep this link in mind.