# Is it possible to use TFS's Source control for the team but Git locally?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I am in a situation where the team is using TFS native source control. But I would like to have a local Git repository so that I can roll back changes and make branches for my own use and experimenting, rather then check-in to the team source repository.

Is this possible with VS 2015? And if so how would I set this up?

Comment: might want to check out this: https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs, doesn't mention support for TFS 2015 though

Answer (score 4):

Yes. [Git-tf](https://gittf.codeplex.com/) and [Git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) both support converting TFVC repositories into Git repositories and allowing you to turn your Git commits into TFVC checkins and others' TFVC checkins into Git commits in your local repository.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of options:

- Git-TFS which works as a bridge: https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs
- Set the `.git` folder to a different spot so your local commandline can understand git, yet TFVC keeps working for remote action: [Disable git in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101211/disable-git-in-visual-studio-2013)

Answer (score 0):

You can consider shelvesets. So you can shelve pending changes, which won’t affect actual source repository, you can unshelve the changes if you want to get pervious shelveset.

More information, you can refer to [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/suspend-your-work-manage-your-shelvesets) article.